# Java: change InputStream data

Tags: java, java-io

I read a file like

```
a b c
e f g
h i j
```

into `InputStream input` object.

```
public void simlplifiedMethod() {
    InputStream input = getInputStream(); // pull information from 3rd party services
    changeInputInformation(input);
    OutputStream output = getOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copyLarge(input, output); // Google utility
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Then I copy `input` into `output`.

**Question:** How to make `IOUtils.copyLarge(input, output)` copy

```
1 2 3
e f g
h i j
```

into `output`?

**UPDATE:**

How to read the first line of `InputStream` with `readLine` method (with buffering) and then proceed work with it via `read` method? Can I use `BufferedReader`? I worry about performance issues, because I heard that `BufferedReader` is slower than `InputStream` anyway.

Comment: You should rewrite the file.

Comment: Read from the input into a String and replace it from the String.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that's impossible.

Comment: It is not impossible. It is the only way. Accomplish modifying a data stream **is** impossible.

Comment: @AnubianNoob that String could be > 2 GB

Comment: @V_B Read from the stream in chunks. Or replace it as you use it.

Comment: *that String could be > 2 GB* please provide your exact problem. We don't really like questions showing [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/182862).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza look at updated version please

Comment: @AnubianNoob look at updated question please

Comment: You should change the data when writing in your `OutputStream`. Seems that you cannot use `IOUtils.copyLarge(input, output);` in this case, but instead copy the code from the method and adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for your tip! I'm newcomer in IO. So could you advice how to do that? Can I use something more user friendly like (I mean wrap `InputStream`) or that'll decrease performance?

Comment: Access to code of `IOUtils.copyLarge` (since this library is open source), then copy the code, adapt it to your needs, probably using something like `if (<condition_to_check_first_line) { /* write 1 2 3 */} else { /* write content from InputStream */ }`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I put my new questioninto UPDATEd section

Comment: @V_B wrap the `InputStream` into a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and use `readLine` to read a complete line from the stream. Then, evaluate if needs to be replaced. Also, it would be better wrapping the `OutputStream` into a [`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) as well.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza can you explain your considerations please? Why tou recommend `BufferedReader` even it's slower?

Comment: @V_B `BufferedReader` is faster than you think. Try it first, then come back. Note: I use BufferedReader and BufferedWriter and can transform and rewrite files of 2 GBs in less than 3 minutes, but this also depends on hardware performance rather than just Java side.

Comment: Don't we have >2GB RAMs nowadays?:) You could always work with strings, stringbuffers.

Comment: @MarianP using this approach you can copy files that big using less than 256MB ram.